# В каком падеже должно стоять слово «стиль»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать, я сама сообразить не могу:
*Она не понимала **стиль** этой команды.*
Или
*Она не понимала **стиля** этой команды.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Она не понимала стиля этой команды.**

[Розенталь §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование.

1) **Родительный падеж,** имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется **в следующих случаях:**

3) **при глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания** (видеть, слышать, **понимать**, думать, знать, хотеть, желать, ожидать и т.п.)